# what's the ideal way to store files in spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, file-upload

I am working with one spring boot maven application, so here on registration form customer has to upload two documents.

1. License
2. PAN card.

so these documents i am storing on physical location and path i am keeping in DB.

So to store License i have created one folder `customerLicense` under proejct root folder parellet to `POM` and for PAN card also i created `customerPANcard` folder on same location parellel to  `POM`.

and in `yml` file i have made entry for path, so in code i am reading folder location and storing documents.

```
    application:
        customerLicensePath: /customerLicense
        customerPANPath: /customerPANcard
```

So to build the project i run command `mvn clean install` under the root folder where `POM` is there. then `target` folder generated and to run the  war i run command `java -jar ./target jarName.war`  that command also i run from root folder.

i don't go inside `target` because those folder where i am keeping documents that are under project root folder, if i run war file from target folder then will not be able to access those folders.

**Here my question is** :- Now if i give this war file to client , so first client has to create two folder manually to store documents otherwise he will get error in file upload.

Do we have option like that client don't have to do anything he will only run war file and automatically these folder should get created ?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createDirectories-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-

Comment: @JBNizet  i am new in spring boot application ... so generally people create manually directory first ?

Comment: Generally, people don't store anything in files. They use a database or a storage service, that can be used by several machines, or in the cloud. But if you want to create directories programmatically, sure, you can. Click the link I posted to know how.

Answer (score 0):

A few things.

1. You don't want to put things 'parallel' to the `pom.xml`. Do this instead:

   ```
   projectRoot/src/main/java/uniquePackageNameHere/ // all your code in here
              /pom.xml
   ```
2. If you want the client to provide the files themselves, simply accept the path at runtime. Something like `java -jar jarName.jar -license /path/to/license -pan /path/to/pan` (use Apache Commons-cli or something)
3. If instead you want to provide the files, then include them in the `resources` folder of your project:

   ```
   src/main/resources/customerLicense
   src/main/resources/customerPANcard
   ```

then, in your code, refer to the files by calling:

```
Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("customerLicense")
Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("customerPANcard")
```

This will make it such that wherever the code is run from, your program will always go in `resources` to find them.

Comment: this code "Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("customerLicense") "where i have to written ? ...  in main class where we have @SpringBootApplication annotation ?

Comment: @HarishBagora don't use that. That would be useful to **read** files bundled with the application jar/war. Not to write to a directory on the file system

Comment: maybe I misunderstood the question